# How to replace relative pronoun "was" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

This is how I would *say* the following sentence, but when I *write* it in a formal e-mail, how can I replace the "was" which seems too colloquial for this register:

> Der Cataloger macht genau das, **was** er beschrieben hat.

If I replace it with "das", it sounds misconstructed and doesn't seem to express the same idea:

> Der Cataloger macht genau das, **das** er beschrieben hat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely not colloquial to use `was` to [introduce a relative clause](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Attribut/Relativ/Einleitung.html) in your example. Since your relative clause **refers to a neuter, undetermined personal pronoun** (`das`), starting the relative clause with `was` is grammatically correct. Regarding the pronoun `was`, see also [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/was_etwas_manches_vieles_einiges) and [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-wer-was.html).

But it's important that it may be correct to introduce a relative clause using `das`. It **depends mainly on the word the relative clause refers to** (its object). Some examples:

> 1) Der Cataloger erfüllt genau **die Aufgabe**, **die** er erfüllen soll.
>
> 2) Der Cataloger tut **nichts**, **was** er nicht tun soll.
>
> 3) Der Cataloger liefert genau **das Ergebnis**, **das** er liefern soll.

In those examples, 1) has a determined feminine object; 2) has an undetermined neuter object; and 3) has a determined neuter object of the relative clause. So, 3) is an example where `das` would be correct to introduce the relative clause.

If you want to maintain the verb "beschreiben", you could use:

> Der Cataloger arbeitet genau so wie beschrieben.

I assume that the "cataloger" is some sort of software component. If it's about a human fulfilling a certain task, however, other phrasing may be preferable. A (purely academic?) example:

> Der Politiker tut genau **das**, **was** er im Wahlkampf versprochen hat [zu tun].